# find value in range of cells and return sum of core

Tags: excel

assume

> 1. the column range A10:A12 has a column of names; bob and mary
> 2. the column range B10:B12 has a list of "scores" for bob and mary
> 3. cell A1 says "bob"

how can i get cell A2 to search A10:A12(name column) for all occurrences of A1("bob") and return the average of those corresponding column b rows?

for instance if "bob" is entered twice in A10:A12 and he has scores in B10:B12 of 50 and 100.  how can i get cell A2 to calculate 75?

can this be done without VBA?

Comment: [AVERAGIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment by [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) , you can use AVERAGEIF().

Cell A2 formula should be =AVERAGEIF(A10:A12;A1;B10:B12)